# Thompson Sampling: Adding positive rewards to Negative rewards in Python for Artificial Intelligence

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

in Chapter 5 of AI Crash Course, the author writes

```
 nSelected = nPosReward + nNegReward 

for i in range(d):
    print('Machine number ' + str(i + 1) + ' was selected ' + str(nSelected[i]) + ' times')
print('Conclusion: Best machine is machine number ' + str(np.argmax(nSelected) + 1))
```

Why are the number of negative rewards added to the number of positive rewards? To find the best machine shouldn't we only be concerned about the machine with the most positive rewards? I'm confused as to why we need to add the negative with the positive rewards.  Also I understand that this is a simulation where you randomly assign successes and and you pre assign success rates. However in a real life situation, how do you know the success rates of each slot machine ahead of time? And how do you know which machines should be assigned a "1" ? Thank you so much!   Here is the full code:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np

# Setting conversion rates and the number of samples
conversionRates = [0.15, 0.04, 0.13, 0.11, 0.05]
N = 10000
d = len(conversionRates)


# Creating the dataset
X = np.zeros((N, d))

for i in range(N):

    for j in range(d):
        if np.random.rand() < conversionRates[j]:
            X[i][j] = 1


# Making arrays to count our losses and wins
nPosReward = np.zeros(d)
nNegReward = np.zeros(d)


# Taking our best slot machine through beta distribution and updating its losses and wins
for i in range(N):
    selected = 0
    maxRandom = 0


    for j in range(d):
        randomBeta = np.random.beta(nPosReward[j] + 1, nNegReward[j] + 1)
        if randomBeta > maxRandom:
            maxRandom = randomBeta
            selected = j


    if X[i][selected] == 1:
        nPosReward[selected] += 1
    else:
        nNegReward[selected] += 1






# Showing which slot machine is considered the best

nSelected = nPosReward + nNegReward 

for i in range(d):
    print('Machine number ' + str(i + 1) + ' was selected ' + str(nSelected[i]) + ' times')
print('Conclusion: Best machine is machine number ' + str(np.argmax(nSelected) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

With more and more feedback, Thompson Sampling shifts its focus more and more from exploration to exploitation. That is, with large `nSelected` values across the board (due to the large `N`), all Beta distributions will be quite concentrated around their mean (`nPosReward[i]/nSelected[i]`) and for larger iterations, with increasing probability, Thompson Sampling will pick the machine that it thinks is the most rewarding. By looking at a long enough horizon, you are pushing the probability of seeing the best considered machine also being the most often picked machine close to 1.

To sum up, your intuition is correct. The machine that is the most rewarding in expectation (given the observed feedback so far) is the one that has the highest empirical mean. Due to the probabilistic phenomena I just described, if you run the algorithm for long enough, the most frequently picked and the machine with highest expected reward will coincide with probability approaching 1.

About the second part of your question, we don't know the success rates. If we knew them, the optimal algorithm would simply pick the ones with the highest success rate at all times. What we do have in real life is observing outputs from these random processes. For example, when you show an online advertisement, you don't know the probability of them clicking. However, with a gross simplification assuming everybody behaves the same way, by showing it to people and observing whether they click it or not, we learn the success rate on the fly.

Comment: Thank you.. However I'm confused as to why we need to add the negative with the positive rewards, to pick the best machines. Don't we only need to know the positive rewards? Why add the negative rewards to it?

Comment: Suppose we have two machines with success rates [0.9, 0.1]. Let's say we sampled the first one once and received a positive reward and we sampled the other five times and received two positive rewards. Should we prefer the second one over the first because of more total positive rewards? Considering number of observations (i.e. sum of positive and negative rewards) allows you to capture the confidence of your current estimate. I think your intuition has an inherent assumption that we sampled the machines uniformly, in which case looking at positive rewards would have been enough.

Comment: As a follow-up, you might think looking at the empirical mean (positive/(positive+negative)) would have been sufficient. That approach circumvents my previous example, but for example if we instead had the empirical means as [1/1, 98/100], it would have picked the first over the other. However, there is a good chance first one was a lucky outcome from a worse machine than the second. Taking into account the total number of trials avoids such issues.

Comment: My apologies. I still don't follow. In the code above the number of times a machine was selected is equal to the number of positive rewards from that machine plus the number of negative rewards from that machine. Why is the machine considered "selected" when it receives a negative reward? If a machine gets 0 positive rewards and 3 negative rewards over all the iterations, why are we selecting that machine 3 times ?(0+3=3).  I've seen code where they only add the positive rewards as the # of times the machine is selected. Why does the code above add both? Is it possible that this is an error?ty

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem setting. In order to observe the feedback, you have to select the machine first. A selected machine’s output is observed as positive of negative. Reading a bit about Multi-Armed Bandit Problem may help with clarifying what is known and what is not

Answer (score 0):

Steven,
*(I'm writing this almost 7 months after you posted. Hopefully you will reply and share some of your own insights, and the code that you used to gain the insight.  I started the AI Crash Course in the end of November 2020, and similarly I was curious about the Thompson sampling in chapter 5.  In my case I was interested mostly in the cases when Thompson Sampling doesn't select the best machine. I was curious how often the 'worst machine' was selected.  So over the past six weeks I've likely tried over a thousand different variations of code to gain some insight. I've likely made over a thousand coding mistakes and hundred different rabbit holes, in an attempt to "catch" when Thompson doesn't work. As well as understand how the betaRandom function and adding the posRewards and NegRewards works. Likely there are mistakes in the following code, and the overall approach to better insight could be made more graphical, so please be kind.:-)*

curlycharcoal provides some insight in his thoughtful answers. Even Hadelin in the same chapter offers the reader a lot of insight.    What follows is an attempt at an "iterative", "trap the errors" approach that helped me gain some insight.  We can try something like the code below and "compare" the result of posReward+negReward vs posRewardOnly.

Consider the following:  First, insert a few lines of code that:  accumulates posRewardsOnly. Also, insert some additional parameters to the concluding print statement so you can see the results of both.  Also insert the true values of the conversion rates (i.e. the mean of the X values) so you can show the actual conversion rates used.  Remove the multiple print statements about the selections for the other machines, just to clean up the output.

Second, create a large loop over most of Hadelin's original code.  Then iterate over that loop. Since we inserted the posRewardOnly result into the concluding print you can compare the results of when you add in the negative rewards, vs selecting the best machine with positive rewards only.  (You can think of this outer loop as a crude "AI" test environment, wherein you gain insight into which approach is a better performer. )

We even insert an array at each iteration, for which machine is selected correctly that compares the with negativeRewards vs posRewardsOnly and graph that at the end.  ( I haven't done this but would be fun to see )

We can also insert an array to keep track of the original betaRandom selections on the inner loop compared to the actual best machine, and see how that selection does a drunkards walk over each time step, and eventually sobers up and selects the best machine if N is large enough usually say a few thousand time steps N>5000.

Also, we can compare if there are times where the best machine isn't selected (this will provide some insight into the error rates, of the Thompson Sampling overall), with five machines, and N=600 it's interesting to see sometimes as much as25% the best machine is not selected, and sometimes, even the worst machine is selected (although rarely).

Also, as curlycharcoal noted, that negative rewards aren't always assigned through every N, for every machine, they're only assigned when the result of the betarandom function returns a maxValue, then that machine is selected to provide  "a sample".   That said, if you play with the code below you might find out that your posOnlyReward idea may perform better, and converge faster than the Pos+Neg reward... or does it? ;-)

---

---

```
######################################################################
# Try and catch when Thompson fails:
# Also, compare performance of selecting 
# based on negRewards+posRewards vs just posRewards
# 03 Jan 2021 JFB
#
#######################################################################
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Note the following are the target conversion rates. 
# Further down pls remember to compare actual rates against selected machine.
# Also, in later versions reorder the rates from low to hi and visa-versa
# to determine if there is some "greedy Thompson" bias
# based on order of best rates.
conversionRates = [0.15, 0.04, 0.13, 0.11, 0.05]# hadelins AI Crash Course

N = 200   
# Increasing N improves the result, Hadelin explains this  in same chapter
# I've found that 10,000 results in about 1% error
# 2000 in about 20% error give or take when using 
# Hadelin's original conversion rates above.
# 100 results results in about 48% error, 
# and posRewards + negRewards disagree with posRewardOnly varying percent,
# my initial sampling of this indicates will be tricky to determine which
# performs better over a variety of situations.  But Hadelin provides code
# to create "tests" with various input states and policies.

catchLimit = 100

d = len(conversionRates)
wrong = 0.0
pcntWrong = 0.0

selectedWrong = 0.0

posOnlyWrong = 0.0
pcntPosOnlyWrong = 0.0

posOnlyVsActual = 0.0
pcntPosOnlyVsActual = 0.0

nSelectedArgMax = -1
NSelectedArgMaxPosOnly = -1

for ii in range( 1, catchLimit):

    ################---- Original X generator----##########################
    #creating the set of the bandit payouts at each time t.
    # Five columns, many rows. 
    # a 1 value means the the slot machine 
    # paid out if you selected that machine at this point in time.
    # this can be improved upon so we can order 
    # the best to worst, and visa vs.
    #
    X = np.zeros((N, d))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(d):
            if np.random.rand() < conversionRates[j]:
                X[i][j] = 1

    Xmean = X.mean(axis=0)
    ##############-- end of the Original X generator----###################
    
    #make arrays to count  rewards from the table of losses and wins.
    nPosReward = np.zeros(d)
    nNegReward = np.zeros(d)
    
    #Taking our best slot machine through beta distribution 
    # and updating its losses and wins.
    # Taking some of the slot machines through the beta distribution, 
    # with the goal of 
    # determining which slot machine is the best. 
    # because sometimes the best slot machine isn't found.
    for i in range(N):
        selected = 0
        maxRandom = 0
        for j in range(d):
            randomBeta = np.random.beta(nPosReward[j] + 1, 
                                        nNegReward[j] + 1)
            if randomBeta > maxRandom:
                maxRandom = randomBeta
                selected = j
        if X[i][selected] == 1:
            nPosReward[selected] +=1
        else:
            nNegReward[selected] +=1
            
    nSelected = nPosReward + nNegReward
    nSelectedPosOnly = nPosReward
    
    nSelectedArgMax = np.argmax(nSelected) + 1
    nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly = np.argmax(nSelectedPosOnly) + 1
    
    XMeanArgMax = np.argmax(Xmean) + 1  # find the actual true best slot machine

    if ( nSelectedArgMax != XMeanArgMax and
        XMeanArgMax != nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly):
        #for i in range(d):
            #print('Machine number ' + str(i+1) + ' was selected ' + str(nSelected[i]) + ' times')
        print('Fail: Pos&Neg predct slot ' + str(nSelectedArgMax),
              'posOnly predct ' + str(nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly),
             'But Xconv rates', Xmean,'actual best=',XMeanArgMax,'<>' )
        wrong +=1
     
    elif ( nSelectedArgMax != XMeanArgMax and
             XMeanArgMax == nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly):
        
        print('PosOnly==Actual pos&neg ' + str(nSelectedArgMax),
              'posOnly predct ' + str(nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly),
             'But Xconv rates', Xmean,'actual best=',XMeanArgMax,'*' )
        selectedWrong +=1
        
    elif ( nSelectedArgMax == XMeanArgMax and
                 XMeanArgMax != nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly):
        print('PosNeg==Actual predcts ' + str(nSelectedArgMax),
              'posOnly predct ' + str(nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly),
             'But Xconv rates', Xmean,'actual best=',XMeanArgMax,'***' )
        posOnlyWrong +=1
        
    elif ( nSelectedArgMax == nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly and
                 XMeanArgMax != nSelectedArgMax):
        print('PosNeg == PosOnly but != actual ' + str(nSelectedArgMax),
              'posOnly predct ' + str(nSelectedArgMaxPosOnly),
             'But Xconv rates', Xmean,'actual best=',XMeanArgMax,'<>' )
        wrong +=1  
        
pcntWrong = wrong / catchLimit * 100
pcntSelectedWrong = selectedWrong / catchLimit * 100
pcntPosOnlyVsActual = posOnlyWrong / catchLimit * 100

print('Catch Limit =', catchLimit, 'N=', N)
print('<>wrong: pos+neg != Actual, and PosOnly != Actual  Failure Rate=  %.1f' %pcntWrong, '%')
print('* PosOnly == Actual but Actual != pos+neg  Failure rate =  %.1f' %pcntSelectedWrong,'%')
print('** pos+Neg == Actual but Actual != PosOnly  Failure rate =   %.1f' %pcntPosOnlyVsActual, '%')

############# END #################
```